# How to get all computer accounts in an another domain using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get all computer accounts from the another domain.

Here is my PowerShell script:

```
$environment = "myDomain"
$strCategory = "computer"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=" + $environment + ",dc=com")
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher ("LDAP://dc=" + $environment + ",dc=com")
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.Filter = ("(objectCategory=$strCategory)")
$colProplist = "name"
foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)| Out-Null}  
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
 foreach ($objResult in $colResults) {
   $objComputer = $objResult.Properties
   Write-output $objComputer.name
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception calling "FindAll" with "0" argument(s): "A referral was returned from the server.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: what is your FQDN domain name? Using your script in my domain do a great job!

Answer (score 4):

I experienced a similar issue--I found that if I specified a server that was a GC and the port that I was able to succeed. I was using the PowerShell Get-AdUser cmdlet, but my scenario was similar (trying to query a universal group membership from a child domain).

```
get-aduser -server fqdn.gc.root.domain:3268
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this :

```
$dn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://DCIpAddress:389/dc=dom,dc=fr","administrator@dom.fr","admin")

# Here look for a user
$Rech = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dn)
$Rech.filter = "((userPrincipalName=phocquet@dom.fr))"
$Rech.SearchScope = "subtree"
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");  
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastLogon");  
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("otherHomePhone"); # téléphone domicile autre

$liste = $Rech.FindAll()
```

It's the same as your code, but here I target a DC (you'd better target a domain  DNS name)and I authenticate my connnexion. If the other domain is in the same forest, you can use the Enterprise admin account, if the other domain is in another forest, or in a trusted domain, use the administrator of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Very much like [atguilmette's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2784508/atguilmette) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18831792/2392683) to this very question, I was able to get the [Active Directory Cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx) to work against a different domain than my current domain by specifying the `-Server` parameter. (Unlike that answer, I did not need to explicitly target a GC machine with a specific port. Perhaps my environment is special...)

```
Get-ADGroup the-group-in-the-other-domain -Server other.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Quest's AD cmdlets offer a command specifically for connecting to another domain: Connect-QADService.

I've successfully used this in production.